# Result of symbolic integration changed drastically by making assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I would like to know the underlying reason for different outcomes for the two integration operation below. One of them includes a few assumptions, otherwise both have the same integrand:

```
Clear[a, b, c, d]
Integrate[(1/(a q^2 + b q Cos[θ] - c) - 1/(a q^2 + b q Cos[θ] + c)), {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
  Assumptions -> {a, c, b} ∈ Reals]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[-((2 Log[-((c - b q + a q^2)/Sqrt[-c^2 + b^2 q^2 - 2 a c q^2 - a^2 q^4])])/ Sqrt[-c^2 + b^2 q^2 - 2 a c q^2 - a^2 q^4]) + (2 Log[(c - b q + a q^2)/ Sqrt[-c^2 + b^2 q^2 - 2 a c q^2 - a^2 q^4]])/Sqrt[-c^2 + b^2 q^2 - 2 a c q^2 - a^2 q^4] + (2 (-Log[-((c + q (b - a q))/Sqrt[-c^2 + b^2 q^2 + 2 a c q^2 - a^2 q^4])] ....
> ```

```
Integrate[(1/(a q^2 + b q Cos[θ] - c) - 1/(a q^2 + b q Cos[θ] + c)), {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

> ```
> -((2 π Sqrt[1 - (2 b q)/(-c + q (b + a q))])/( c + q (b - a q))) - 
>  (2 π)/((c + q (b + a q)) Sqrt[1 - (2 b q)/(c + q (b + a q))])
> ```

Comment: Well, in the first one you tell *Mathematica* that `a`, `b` and `c` are real whereas in the second *Mathematica* treats them as complex as that's the default assumption.

Comment: @RunnyKine So the second outcome should reduce to the first (more lengthy) output when a,b,c real?

Comment: Well, the first one appears lengthy because it's a `ConditionalExpression`. So it's giving you various answers that correspond to different combinations of `a`, `b` and `c` in the `Reals`.

Comment: The second outcome is applicable to more general conditions, and should reduce to the first with application of those a,b,c combinations, how do you show this?

Comment: Probably not as simple as it seems, running `Assuming[{a, c, b} \[Element] Reals, FullSimplify[ eq1 == eq2]]` does not simplify to `True` (where `eq1` and `eq2` are the respective integral outputs)

Comment: Checked the reliability of second output using                                                    Clear[a, b, c, q]
dfg3[a_, b_, c_, q_] := 
 NIntegrate[(1/(a q^2 + b q Cos[\[Theta]] - c) - 1/(
    a q^2 + b q Cos[\[Theta]] + c)), {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]

dfg4[a_, b_, c_, 
  q_] := -((2 \[Pi] Sqrt[1 - (2 b q)/(-c + q (b + a q))])/(
   c + q (b - a q))) - (2 \[Pi])/((c + q (b + a q)) Sqrt[1 - (2 b q)/(c + q (b + a q))])
Plot[ {dfg3[0.45, 0.1, 0.1, q], dfg4[0.45, 0.1, 0.1, q]}, {q, 2, 5}]